# Alamofire - is there a way to set a custom default queue to handle all request callbacks

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I know there's a way to provide a custom queue for a particular callback, but most of my requests don't need to be handled on the main thread, so it would be much cleaner if I could just set the default once, and override with the main thread when needed...

P.S.
I have server class that all requests pass through - so it could add some default params to each request, print some debug info if needed, and perform some basic validation... So if I could set the default queue there and have it passed on to the next handlers, it would also be a good solution...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this `Request`'s method (actually there are more with queue parameter). It let you define callback queue.

```
public func response(
        queue queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil,
        completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void)
        -> Self
```

Comment: hey thanks, I noticed this method, but I was looking for a way to provide a default queue, that will apply to all requests, without me needing to specify it every time....